# What difference between <T extends Foo> and <? extends Foo>?

Tags: java, generics

I have following code:

```java
abstract public class Base {
    private static final HashMap<Integer, ? extends Base> hashMap = new HashMap<>();

    public static <T extends Base> void put(Integer key, T val) {
        hashMap.put(key, val);
    }

    public static <T extends Base> T get(Integer key) {
        return hashMap.get(key);
    }
}
```

So, i got incompatible types at `Base.put()` method: `<T extends Base>` and `<? extends Base>`.

What difference and how to rewrite that code properly?

Comment: You cannot as it stands. Wildcard generics mean “some specific type within these bounds but I don’t know what”. `?` means “and I also don’t care”. But it is still a single specific type. Your `put` method allows the caller to specify the type - so there is no way the compiler can guarantee type safety. Remove the generics, make it all `Base`, and that will work just fine.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I just tried to clarify type inheritance with generics, but it wasn't necessary, i got it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite simple:

? - is a **wildcard**

T - is a **generic type**

They are similar but different. If you want to **enforce** the type,them you cannot use a wildcard. You have to use generics

**Example**

```
public <T extends Number> void copy(List<T> dest,List<T> src){
    //code
}
```

The code above will be able to copy a list from src, to dest.  Both src and dest have the same generic type, so it is safe to copy each element.

```
public void copy(List<? extends Number> dest, List<? extends Number> src){
    //code
}
```

The code above is not very good. dest could be of type List<**Integer**> while src could be of type List<**Double**>

I hope this helps